# Java: How to check for a string before saving data to text file?

Tags: java

I'm creating an employee time clock for a java class. This portion of my program needs to check if there is a "punch in time" before accepting a "punch out time".

When I only use an `if` loop, that portion seems to work. When I add the `else`, it ignores the `if` and just performs `else`.

Can I get some feedback on a better way to approach this?

```
public static void punchIn() throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Date and time (format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss): ");
    String timeentry = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the employee ID number: ");
    String idnumber = sc.nextLine() + " ";

    String inorout = "in";

    System.out.println("The Punch-in date / time is: " + timeentry);
    System.out.println("The employee ID number is: " + idnumber);
    System.out.println("The employee is punched-" + inorout);

    PunchinPunchoutData product = new PunchinPunchoutData();
    product.setTimeentry(timeentry);
    product.setIdnumber(idnumber);
    product.setInorout(inorout);

    productDAO.punchIn(product);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Press enter to continue ");
    sc.nextLine();
}


public static void punchOut() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Date and time (format MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss): ");
    String timeentry = sc.nextLine();

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("timeclock1.txt"));

    String line = "";

    System.out.print("Enter an employee ID number: ");
    String idnumber = sc.next() + " ";//read the choice
    sc.nextLine();// discard any other data entered on the line

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.contains(idnumber + " ") && line.endsWith("in")) {
            break;
        }

        else  { 
            System.out.println("There is no punch-in record for ID number: 
            " + idnumber);
            System.out.println("A punch-in entry must be saved first");
            punchIn();
            break;
        }
    }

    String inorout = "out";

    System.out.println("The Punch-out date / time is: " + timeentry);
    System.out.println("The employee ID number is: " + idnumber);
    System.out.println("The employee is punched-" + inorout + ".");

    PunchinPunchoutData product = new PunchinPunchoutData();
    product.setTimeentry(timeentry);
    product.setIdnumber(idnumber);
    product.setInorout(inorout);

    productDAO.punchOut(product);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Press enter to continue ");
    sc.nextLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are reading a file line by line to check if the employee has a "punch in" record. In your code, you are calling `punchIn` the moment you have a line that does not belong to the employee, which will most probably add a "punch-in" everytime `punchOut` is called. You should loop over the whole file, and only call `punchIn` when no line in the file contains a record.

```
boolean foundPunchIn = false;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(idnumber + " ") && line.endsWith("in")) {
       foundPunchIn = true;
       break;
    }   
}

if(!foundPunchIn) {
    System.out.println("There is no punch-in record for ID number: " + idnumber);
    System.out.println("A punch-in entry must be saved first");
    punchIn();
}

String inorout = "out";
...
```

Comment: Success. There must have been another problem in the code, but your solution was simple and worked after I did some troubleshooting. Thanks!